# Loading data from a json file into extjs

Tags: json, extjs4

I have a .json file whose content is supposed to be read by Ext.data.Store and displayed by Ext.grid.Panel (extjs 4). However, no data is displayed, only the grid is. The code is:

```
var user = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'user',
    model: 'User',
    autoLoad: 'true',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/users.json',
        reader: {type: 'json', root: 'blah'}
    }
});

 Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
    store :user,
    id : 'user',
    title: 'Users',
    columns : [ 
        {header: 'ID',     dataIndex : 'id'}, 
        {header : 'NAME',  dataIndex : 'name'}, 
        {header : 'Email', dataIndex: 'email'}
    ],
    height :300,
    width: 400,
    renderTo:'my-portlet2'
});
```

and my json file is:

```
{ blah[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ed Spencer",
    "email": "ed@sencha.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Abe Elias",
    "email": "abe@sencha.com"
  }
]}
```

Inline data gets displayed but when i am trying to read from a json file, it does not work. I am using firefox and firebug says that there is an error loading the script from my .js file. Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: what does the error say? can you load the file if you copied the URL that the GET request tried to execute and paste it into the browser?

Comment: The json you provided is not valid. Are you sure you have a valid json in your users.json file?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot everyone. It is working fine now. The server could not find the files because the path was not proper. After experimenting a bit, I was finally able to fetch the json data from the json file by giving a proper path, like - "TestPortlet3-portlet/js/example.json". Initially, I was only giving "/example.json" or "users.json". On keeping the .json file in the correct folder and giving the correct path, I was able to display the json data :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ "blah": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ed Spencer",
    "email": "ed@sencha.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Abe Elias",
    "email": "abe@sencha.com"
  }
]}
```

Comment: I made the correction but it still didnt work. The error says that the resource is not found (404). What could be the error? I tried specifying the absolute path but to no avail. For additional information, I am running this extjs app as a liferay MVC portlet which uses tomcat. I tried keeping the file in the webapps directory and everywhere possible I could think of. I made the corresponding changes each time too. Cant think of anything :(

Comment: The firebug complains that 'ext-all-debug.js' and 'ext-all.js' are not found (404). Also, 'ext' is not defined. I have the 2 js files in the extjs folder and am also giving the same path in the script. It also says 'yui: not loaded: delayed task' I am lost as to where I am going wrong..... Suggestions plz?

Comment: If I'm honest, your problem is completely different to the subject of this question. I'd repost an new question. Anyway, your path to the ext script is probably broken in your index.html (or something like this), would help if you submit your index.html file; also, if you go to the examples folder under extjs, can you any example project?