# How to fetch JSON data in extJS grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am loading this data from my store. Can anybody please explain me how to load data dynamically. By using Ajax.

My COde

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Now data I will put in some json file. MY question is how to fetch JSON data in extJS grid store. How to rewrite the STore code

Comment: Hi David refer this link for example & explaination:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918030/loading-data-from-a-json-file-into-extjs

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the Ext.data.Store to use an Ext.data.proxy.Proxy to load data from the server.

> Ext.data.proxy.Ajax - sends requests to a server on the same domain
>
> Ext.data.proxy.JsonP - uses JSON-P to send requests to a server on a
>   different domain
>
> Ext.data.proxy.Rest - uses RESTful HTTP methods
>   (GET/PUT/POST/DELETE) to communicate with server Ext.data.proxy.Direct
>   - uses Ext.direct.Manager to send requests

docs: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy.html

code sample: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html